# KFold function TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Tags: python, function, typeerror, k-fold, argmax

I defined a function to print K fold scores and determine the best c but I'm getting an error in this line in the code below(I've highlighted the line in the code as well):

*best_c = results_table.loc[results_table['Mean recall score'].idxmax()]['C_parameter']*

```
# Ad hoc function to print k_fold scores

def printing_Kfold_scores(x_train_data, y_train_data):
fold = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=False)

# Different c parameters (hyperparameter for K-fold)
c_param_range = [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]

results_table = pd.DataFrame(index = range(len(c_param_range), 2), columns = 
['C_parameter_r', 'Mean recall score'])
results_table['C_parameter'] = c_param_range

# the. k-fold will gove 2 lists: train and test indices
j=0
for c_param in c_param_range:
    print('------------------------------------------')
    print('C parameter: ', c_param)
    print('------------------------------------------')
    print('')
    
    recall_accs=[]
    for iteration, indices in enumerate(fold.split(x_train_data), start=1):
        
        #Calling the logistic regression model
        lr = LogisticRegression(C = c_param, penalty = 'l1', solver='liblinear')
        
        lr.fit(x_train_data.iloc[indices[0],:], 
y_train_data.iloc[indices[0],:].values.ravel())
        
        y_pred_undersample = lr.predict(x_train_data.iloc[indices[1],:].values)
        
        recall_acc = recall_score(y_train_data.iloc[indices[1], :].values, 
y_pred_undersample)
         
        recall_accs.append(recall_acc)
        print('Iteration ', iteration, ': recall_score = ', recall_acc)
        
    results_table.ix[j, 'Mean recall score'] = np.mean(recall_accs)
    
    j+=1
    print('')
    print('Mean recall score: ', np.mean(recall_accs))
    print('')

########################################################################################
best_c = results_table.loc[results_table['Mean recall score'].idxmax()['C_parameter']
########################################################################################
#This is where I get the error#

#Checking best c parameter

print('********************************************************************************')
print('Best c parameter : ', best_c)
print('********************************************************************************')


return best_c
```

The error I'm getting is

```
TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype
```

Comment: you probably missed to close the bracket for the .loc? at least the brackets does not match at all.. (without inspecting it in detail)
You can check the dtype by printing `results_table['Mean recall score']` to make sure it contains what you expect

Comment: Think I've closed it. It does contains what I'm expecting but I'm getting the same error @sarbot

Comment: I guess the argmax operation is used within the `idmax()` property. Can you add the missing bracket to your code example too, just to be sure what you try to do in that line.
Have you checked the content of results_table['Mean recall score'] already?